# wxpython app crashing using pjsip with multi-threads

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, pjsip

I'm doing an app with `wxpython` and `pjsip`, I need to use multithreads so each call is handle by it own thread, but for some reason the app is crashing and unexpectedly closing immediately leaving on of the following errors:

```
Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'python' received an X Window System error.
```

This probably reflects a bug in the program.

The error was `RenderBadPicture (invalid Picture parameter)`.

```
python: xcb_io.c:221: poll_for_event: Assertion `(((long) (event_sequence) - (long) (dpy->request)) <= 0)' failed.
```

I read that this happen with multithreads and `wxpython`. I try using `wx.callafter()` and `wx.lib.pubusub.Subscribe`, but I still have the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

Anything from a thread other than the main thread when related to wxPython has to be wrapped in a threadsafe method. There are 3 of these: wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater and wx.PostEvent. If you try to access a wxPython method directly from a separate thread, then you'll almost certainly have issues. Pubsub is awesome, but it's not threadsafe. It too must be wrapped in one of the threadsafe methods.

The [wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks) has several threading examples and I wrote a simple [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/) on the topic as well. If those don't help, then you'll need to create a small, runnable example and post it here or on the wxPython mailing list.